# read streaming data over pipe in python

Tags: python, pipe, streaming

I need to continuously read and process data on one computer that is generated on another computer.

So far, I was able to use `mypipe` tosend data from the second computer to the first, using the following:

```
cat mypipe | ssh second_com@IP_address 'cat destfile'
```

This works and the data is now constantly dumped to `destfile`, but file size increases really fast and this is not the solution I need.

**What I would like to do is pipe the data directly into my python script without writing it to a file**. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: What you've written doesn't dump data to `destfile`. Are you sure you aren't doing `ssh second_com@IP_address 'cat >destfile'` or something like that?

Comment: TCP/ UDP? It also depends a bit on the operating system. One shortcut would be to use something like netcat where one python process writes the data to the respective named pipe or stdout and one reads it respectively on the other side.

Comment: Is this line oriented data? Text or binary? Encoded text like utf-8? On your destination machine you could write a program that does `for line in sys.stdin: do your processing` then run it the same way you run cat on the destination.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written doesn't dump data to `destfile`. What it does is:

- `cat mypipe`: Dumps the contents of a file named `mypipe` to its stdout.
- `|`: Takes the stdout from `cat mypipe` and sends it as the stdin to `ssh`.
- `ssh second_com@IP_address`: Creates an `ssh` connection to another system and runs the specified command there, forwarding its stdin along.
- `'cat destfile'`: Runs the command `cat destfile` on that other system—which ignores the forwarded-in stdin and dumps the contents of a file named `destfile` to stdout, which goes nowhere useful.

What you probably have is something more like this:

```
cat mypipe | ssh second_com@IP_address 'cat >destfile'
```

The difference is:

- `'cat destfile'`: Runs the command `cat >destfile` on that other system—so `cat` just copies the forwarded-in stdin to its stdout, and then `>destfile` causes that stdout to be stored in the local file `destfile`.

So the result is exactly what you described as happening.

---

The most obvious way to change this is to just put your Python program in place of `cat`. Of course you need to put your program on the remote machine, somewhere accessible, like the home directory of that `second_com` user. Then you can execute it like:

```
cat mypipe | ssh second_com@IP_address 'python myscript.py'
```

Now, inside `myscript.py`, it can read from `sys.stdin`, which will be the stream of data coming from `cat mypipe` (via `|` and `ssh`), and you can do whatever it is you wanted to do with that data, without needing to save it to `destfile` first.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer abarnert -- I did drop the > sign, so you are right.

Comment: I just made the simple python script as you suggested, which receives the data (it's the binary data): import sys,  in = sys.stdin.read(), print(len(in)).  However, using the line you suggested:  (cat mypipe | ssh second_com@IP_address 'python myscript.py') makes this program to be executed on the second machine (from which I want to send data) and I need to receive and process the data on the first machine.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this problem. I need to process the data received from second computer in python on the first computer. I understand in @abarnert solution the processing by python script (on first computer) is seen on the second computer. I just want to send the data from the first computer and then run the python script on the first computer......

Comment: @Steve What is the second computer even doing then? Maybe you're looking for the `tee` command? Or maybe you want to put your script into the pipeline between `mypipe` and the second computer (e.g., `python myscript.py < mypipe | ssh second_com@IP_address '…<whatever command you want to run on the second computer, which I can't guess at>'`?